# jQuery execCommand doesn't work as a pop-up in the contenteditable HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I am trying to create inline text editor by jQuery execCommand function. To do this my source code segment is below,

```js
/*******************************************************************/
/********** Click: inner of contenteditable text-editor div ********/
/*******************************************************************/
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() {
   $('.text-editor').on("click", function(e) {
   /******* Start: Click text to Background Change *********/
   $(".text-editor").removeClass("text-click");
   $(this).addClass("text-click");
   /******* End: Click text to Background Change *********/

   /******* START: Click text to tag contenteditable attr. *********/
   $(this).attr("contenteditable","true");
   /******* End: Click text to tag contenteditable attr. *********/

   /******* Start: Click text to Popup class *********/
   $(".text-editor").removeClass("popup");
   $(this).addClass("popup");
   /******* End: Click text to add Popup class *********/

   /******* Start: Click text to Popup Div *********/
   $(".popup-panel").remove();
   var PopupHtml = "<div class='popup-panel show' contenteditable='true'>\
   <button type='button' id='bold-text'><i class='fas fa-bold'></i></button>\
   <button type='button' id='underline-text'><i class='fas fa-underline'></i></button>\
   <button type='button' id='italic-text'><i class='fas fa-italic'></i></button>\
   </div>";

   $('.text-editor').contents().prop('designMode','off');
   $(this).contents().prop('designMode','on');

   if(!$('.popup-panel').length){
    $(this).append( PopupHtml );
   }
   /******* End: Click text to add Popup Div *********/
   e.stopPropagation()
   }); 

   /*******************************************************************/
   /********** Click: outter of contenteditable text-editor div *******/
   /*******************************************************************/
    $(document).on("click", function(e) {
     if ($(e.target).is(".text-editor") === false) {
   /******* Start: Click text to Background Change *********/
   $(".text-editor").removeClass("text-click");
   /******* End: Click text to Background Change *********/

   /******* START: Click text to tag contenteditable attr. *********/
   $(".text-editor").removeAttr("contenteditable");
   /******* End: Click text to tag contenteditable attr. *********/

     /******* Start: Click text to remove Popup class *********/
     $(".text-editor").removeClass("popup");
      /******* End: Click text to add Popup class *********/

     /******* Start: Click text to Popup Div *********/
     $('.text-editor').contents().prop('designMode','off');
     $(".popup-panel").remove();
      /******* End: Click text to add Popup Div *********/
     }
   });


    $('#bold-text').on("click", function(e) {
     document.execCommand('bold',false,null); 
    });

    $('#underline-text').on("click", function(e) {
     document.execCommand('underline',false,null); 
    });

    $('#italic-text').on("click", function(e) {
     document.execCommand('italic',false,null); 
    });


 });
});
```

```css
.text-editor{ background-color: transparent; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; }
.text-click{background-color: lightyellow; border: 1px dashed #ccc;}
*[contenteditable="true"] { outline: 0px solid transparent; }

ul.text-option{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul.text-option li{ list-style: none; display: inline-block; }
ul.text-option li a{ padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-right: 5px; }
button{ margin-right: 5px; }

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup { position: relative; /*display: inline-block;*/ cursor: pointer; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popup-panel {visibility: hidden;/*width: 160px;*/background-color: #555;color: #fff;text-align: center;border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px;position: absolute;z-index: 1;bottom: 125%;left: 50%;margin-left: -80px;}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popup-panel::after {content: "";position: absolute;top: 100%;left: 50%;margin-left: -5px;border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {visibility: visible;-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;animation: fadeIn 1s;}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {from {opacity: 0;} to {opacity: 1;}}

@keyframes fadeIn {from {opacity: 0;}to {opacity:1 ;}}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="box">

  <h1 class="text-editor" contenteditable="true">First Heading Text</h1>
  <h2 class="text-editor">Second Heading Text</h2>
  <h3 class="text-editor">Third Heading Text</h3>
  <h4 class="text-editor">Forth Heading Text</h4>
  <h5 class="text-editor">Fifth Heading Text</h5>
  <p class="text-editor">This is paragraph text</p>
 </div>
```

Problem is that when I am selecting the text inside html contenteditable tag and click on the popup button "Bold"/"Underline"/"Italic" then text is not changing as requirement. 
But it is working if the button set is not popup, such like below

```
    <div class="box">
        <h1 class="text-editor" contenteditable="true">First Heading Text</h1>
        <h2 class="text-editor">Second Heading Text</h2>
        <h3 class="text-editor">Third Heading Text</h3>
        <h4 class="text-editor">Forth Heading Text</h4>
        <h5 class="text-editor">Fifth Heading Text</h5>
        <p class="text-editor">This is paragraph text</p>
    </div>

<ul class="text-option">
    <li><button type="button" id="bold-text"><i class="fas fa-bold"></i></button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="underline-text"><i class="fas fa-underline"></i></button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="italic-text"><i class="fas fa-italic"></i></button></li>
</ul>
```

What is wrong is here? Please someone help me to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

"Obsolete
This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Try to output exec command return, because, it may return false if it's not supported.

```
console.log(document.execCommand('underline',false,null))
```

"When an HTML document has been switched to designMode"
Can you try, to switch execCommand on document?

Next, it shouldn't be the case, but can you run execCommand from jQuery selector, like

```
$(document).execCommand
```